# PUT request returns 406 (Not acceptable) coming from Backbone.js to my REST-ful PHP page

Tags: php, apache, rest, backbone.js, fat-free-framework

I wrote a REST-ful API using Fat Free Framework in PHP, and am making a call using backbone.js. When I try and save a new Orders model my app makes a PUT request, and the server spits back a 406 error.

```
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:406 Not Acceptable

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:174
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:__utma=239804689.76636928.1286699220.1305666110.1325104376.94; __utmz=239804689.1325104376.94.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); PHPSESSID=935d2632fd0d12a1a0df4cb0f392eb5e
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Request Payload
{"id":0,"customerId":0,"lastPage":"items","priceConfig":null,"items":null,"saveStatus":0,"savedAt":1326588395899,"name":null}

Response Headers
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:460
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Sun, 15 Jan 2012 00:46:37 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
Server:Apache
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]

# Disable ETags
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header Unset ETag
    FileETag none
</IfModule>

# Default expires header if none specified (stay in browser cache for 7 days)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A604800
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

My website application works fine on my local server and only does this on my web server. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you added a [`Script`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_actions.html#script) directive somewhere to tell Apache how to handle PUT requests? [See this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php).

Comment: Adding "Script PUT (any directory/file)" gives me a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: In Fat Free Framework (all routing is done through index.php) I route the PUT request to /orders, using: F3::route('PUT /orders', dostuff());   Maybe it's confused that index.php is calling PUT on itself? I don't understand how Apache deals with the routing stuff.

Comment: I suspect you still need the `Script` directive - by default Apache won't invoke PHP scripts to handle PUT requests, so no matter what you configure/write in your PHP code it will never get executed. I had to set up a PHP script to handle PUT requests through Apache once, and I seem to remember to it took me some considerable time to get it to work...

Comment: What message do you see in the Apache log when you get a 500 error?

Comment: [alert] /.htaccess: Script not allowed here

Comment: FYI, that error message is telling you that a `Script` directive is not allowed in a .htaccess file, it must be placed directly into the main configuration files (i.e. httpd.conf). Since you seem to have a shared host there is probably not much you can do about this.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround.

My believe my server is using mod_security2 to block PUT and DELETE requests. I am waiting to hear back from them, and mod_security2 can't be disabled in .htaccess files so there's nothing I can do.

Using "Script PUT /filename" in the .htaccess file was causing a 500 error: "Script not allowed here", I am not sure why, but I decided not to deal with having my web host reconfigured to handle PUT and DELETE.

To keep my API REST-ful, I left in the normal handling of PUT and DELETE, and added this to the POST handling:

```
function post() {
    //if Backbone.emulateHTTP is true, emulate PUT
    $data = json_decode(F3::get('REQBODY'), true);
    $type = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE']; //PUT, DELETE, POST
    if ($type == 'PUT') {
        $this->put();
        return;
    }
    if ($type == 'DELETE') {
        $this->delete();
        return;
    }

    //handle normal POST here
}
```

If you set Backbone.emulateHTTP = true; it keeps the request method as POST and sends the X-HTTP-Method-Override as PUT or DELETE.

I like this because I can keep my REST-ful implementation intact, and just comment out the emulateHTTP code for when I publish to my webserver.

Comment: Update: This workaround worked well, and my host was able to disable mod_security for my site. Which let me change Backbone.emulateHTTP = false; and everything works as expected.